# How do I select difficulty in FoFix/Frets On Fire?

Tags: frets-on-fire

When I choose a song, it says "select a difficulty" and displays the different difficulties, but I don't see any way to choose between them. I try hitting up/down, and manage to select different difficulties somehow, but it's pretty random - I don't see any visual indication of the actual difficulty I'm playing.

What am I missing?

Comment: In Frets on Fire difficulty of a song depends on the song; some songs are written with only Expert difficulty, others with every other difficulty. In FoF, as far as I remember, you are shown only the available difficulties for any song. Dunno about FoFix, maybe that one shows every difficulty, even if they are not available?

Comment: @Ragnar - it's not that, I tried songs that have varying difficulties and simply couldn't see any selection marker, although I did manage to play them at varying difficulties.

Comment: So your problem is a graphical one, then? From what I understand, you're saying that you can't see the marker, but can still choose a different difficulty?

Comment: @Ragnar - yeah, I think this is the case.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots or even a short video might help identifying the issue. After all, FoF/FoFiX is highly themeable, and that might be an issue with just with your theme. (hmm... have you tried selecting another theme?)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I play Frets On Fire, I use the up/down arrow keys to select the difficulty.  The name of the selected level becomes bigger and start flashing.  So, no.  I don't think you're missing anything.

Are you sure you don't have a corrupted game?  You might want to try:

1. Uninstall/Reinstall
2. Uninstall/Redownload/Reinstall

And you can always check to see if it works on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of FoFiX you have.. But you have a FoFiX 4.0 alpha
so you have a problem with select difficulty. It's changing when you strum (up\down) but you can not see it.. I used FoFiX 3.120 final and have not any problem with it. :D